# boost::asio::async_write and buffers over 65536 bytes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a very simple method, with the purpose of responding to an incoming message, and then closing the connection:

```
void respond ( const std::string message )
{ 
  std::string str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";

  Controller & controller = Controller::Singleton(); 
  if ( auto m = handleNewMessage( _message ) )
  {
    auto reply = controller.FIFO( m );
    str.append( reply );
  }
  else
    str.append ( "<Error/>" );

  std::size_t bytes = str.size() * sizeof( std::string::value_type );
  std::cout << "Reply bytesize " << bytes << std::endl;

  boost::asio::async_write(
            socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer( str ),
            boost::bind(
                    &TCPConnection::handle_write,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
                  ));
}


void handle_write ( const boost::system::error_code & error, size_t bytes_transferred )
{
  if ( error )
  {
    std::cerr << "handle_write Error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "handle_write Bytes sent: " << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
      std::cerr << "handle_write Bytes sent: " << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
      socket_.close();
  }
}
```

I know the problem is that boost::asio::async_write does not complete the writing operation, because the output from the above operations is:

```
Reply bytesize: 354275
handle_write Bytes sent: 65536
```

Implying that the maximum buffer size (65536) was not enough to write the data?

Searching around [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432722/boostasioasync-write-writing-data-larger-than-65536-bytes?rq=1), I discovered that my problem is that the buffer created by the method:

```
boost::asio::buffer( str )
```

goes out of scope before the operation has a chance to finish sending all the data.

It seems like I can't use a boost::asio::mutable_buffer, but only a boost::asio::streambuf

Furthermore and more importantly, a second error complains about the actual boost::asio::async_write being passed a boost::asio::const_buffer OR boost::asio::mutable_buffer:

```
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/consuming_buffers.hpp:164:5: error: no type named ‘const_iterator’ in ‘class boost::asio::mutable_buffer’
     const_iterator;
     ^
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/consuming_buffers.hpp:261:36: error: no type named ‘const_iterator’ in ‘class boost::asio::mutable_buffer’
   typename Buffers::const_iterator begin_remainder_;
```

So I am left with only one choice: To use a boost::asio::streambuf

I've tried using:

```
  boost::asio::streambuf _out_buffer;
```

As a class member, and then made method respond:

```
  std::ostream os( &_out_buffer );
  os << str;

  boost::asio::async_write(
            socket_,
            _out_buffer,
            boost::asio::transfer_exactly( bytes ),
            boost::bind(
                    &TCPConnection::handle_write,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
                  ));
```

However, although I get no errors, not the entire data is sent!
So, I am guessing, not the entire string is written into the streambuf?

Alternatively, I would love to know what is the most elegant way to write using boost::asio::async_write, data that is larger than 65536 bytes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex, you understand asio async operations wrong. Your problem is all about lifetime of buffer and socket.
The buffer has to be alive and socket opened during the whole transmition time (from `asio::async_write` call to `handle_write` callback is to be called by Asio `io_service` dispatcher.
To better understand how it works, consider that every time you doing some `boost::asio::async_{operation}` you are posting the pointer to data for operation and pointer to callback function to the job queue. And it's Asio decision  when to execute your job (but of course it tries to do it as faster as possible =)). When the whole (possible big) I/O operation completes the Asio informs you using specified callback. And you can release resources then freely.

So, to get your code work you have to ensure that `std::string str` is still exist and `_socket` not closed until the `handle_write` callback. You can replace the stack allocated `std::string str` variable by some member variable in the class that agregates `_socket`. And move the `socket_.close();` line from `respond` function to `handle_write`.

Hope, I helped you.

P.S. When you do `boost::asio::buffer( str ),` you don't copy content of the string but just create thin wpapper above data of string.

Comment: Yes you did help! Just a moment ago, I moved socket close into the uneventful handle_write! HOWEVER, the problem still remains, even when using a streambuf, the entire contents are not sent, although there is no error anymore

Comment: What about buffer life time? Is it alive during whole transmition time?

Comment: Yes, it is instantiated during the respond method, and not altered until the class object is deleted by asio. I have the suspicion that not all parts of the string are copied, don't know if I'm copying correctly the string into the streambuf

Comment: Try to do it without streambuf by simply using `boost::asio::buffer(data_)`

Comment: It still has the same issue. I am closing the socket too early is my assumption. Can I somehow callback the socket closeown after completion? You are absolutely spot on, I have been confused by the asynchronous nature of it.

Comment: Yes, your are right, you have to accumulate amount of data sent incrementing it by `bytes_transferred` in handler function, and close socket only when the sum of data transfered became equal to `data_.size()`

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help! I am assuming it works, I get the same size of the reply sent. The receiving end (PHP) does not see it all, but at this point, I am assuming the fault is on the PHP side, and not in C++. Again, thank you very much for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
_out_buffer( static_cast<void*>( &str.front() ), bytes );
```

Is only valid when initializing `_out_buffer`, i.e. Before the body of your class's constructor begins.

That code equivalent to

```
_out_buffer.operator()( static_cast<void*>(&str.front()), bytes )
```

Of course there is no such operator in class `mutable_buffer`, and that's what the compiler is complaining about.

I think the simplest thing to do (but not the best), is to change that line to:

```
_out_buffer = boost::asio::mutable_buffer(
    static_cast<void*>( &str.front() ),
    bytes
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've already tried mustable_buffer. Yes it is constructed ok, but the problem remains, the boost::asio::async_write does not like as a parameter (same error as before).